# Is $g$ a monotone sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let a sequence $\{g_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be defined in the following way:
$$g_n=∑_{k=1}^{n^2}\frac{k-1}{n} \chi_{\{f∈[(k-1)/n,k/n)\}} +n\chi_{\{f≥n\}}$$

Must this sequence necessarily be monotone?

where $f$ is a measurable function,
and $\chi$ is the characteristic function of $A$ defined by:

$$\chi_A(x)= \left\{ \array{1 \quad \text{for } x \in A \\ 0 \quad \text{for }x \notin A }\right.$$

Comment: Please define your notation. What is $f$? What is $\chi$? Is $g_n$ a number, a function, ...?

Comment: @GregMartin edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $f(x)=\frac25$ for a particular $x$, then $g_2(x)=0$ and $g_3(x)=\frac13$ and $g_4(x)=\frac14$ and $g_5(x)=\frac25$.